# How to load swagger json file (statically) on my minimal api?

Tags: c#, api, swagger

I'm novice by here ...

I started to develop minimal api in C# in the company where I work ...

I'm using swagger to document my api...

I noticed that the swagger.json is created automatically according to RoutesEndpoints that I create ... as the example:

```
using Microsoft.OpenApi.Models;
using MyMinimalAPI.DB;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(C=>
{
    C.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "MyMinimal API", Description = "MyMinimalAPI", Version = "v1"});
});

var app = builder.Build();
app.UseSwagger();
app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
{
c.SwaggerEndpoint("swagger.json", "MyMinimalAPI V1");
});

app.MapGet("/", () => "Pescarolli API has been running");
app.MapGet("/GetProdutionCode/{OP}", async(string OP) => await MyMinimalAPIDB.GetProdutionCode(OP));

[...]

app.Run();
```

I edited the swagger.json file and customized it in the online editor on the swagger website (https://editor.swagger.io/), now i want to use this "custom" json in my api...
how do i do that?

Comment: What did you customize in the json?

Comment: I added some comments and made some fields enumerated ...

Comment: in addition to filters... (like accepting only number... some rules) ...

Comment: Ideally you should not modify the generated json file and you should try to add those thing (filters, rules etc) via code only. because this file gets generated every time you call swagger ui based on your current APIs. if you try to load static one then that might not reflect the current APIs situations.